# python if multiple string return the words that contains in the sentences

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, matching

I have a list of words and I want to do if statement, below is my list:

```
list = ['camera','display','price','memory'(will have 200+ words in the list)]
```

Here is my code:

```
def check_it(sentences):
    if 'camera' in sentences and 'display' in sentences and 'price' in sentences:
        return "Camera/Display/Price"
    if 'camera' in sentences and 'display' in sentences:
        return "Camera/Display"
    ...
    return "Others"

h.loc[:, 'Category'] = h.Mention.apply(check_it)
```

There will be too many combinations for these and also I want to have the words return to row individually.
Does anyone know how to make this sample and return the word individually instead of doing 'camera/display/price'?

Comment: Your example is not well-expressed. If sentences contains both 'camera' and 'display', then it is unclear what should happen if there is also 'price', since the second if block will never be executed (already returned from previous block).

Comment: Probably the case with the most keywords should be returning first.

Comment: Are the categories in `Category` ordered alphabetically? E.g. `Camera/Price/Display` should return as `Camera/Display/Price`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) by regex - join all values of lists with `|`, last [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) values by `/`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Mention':['camera in sentences and display in sentences',
                              'camera in sentences price']})


L = ['camera','display','price','memory']
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)
df['Category'] = df['Mention'].str.findall(pat).str.join('/')
print (df)
                                        Mention        Category
0  camera in sentences and display in sentences  camera/display
1                     camera in sentences price    camera/price
```

Another solution with list comprehension, also for list use generator with `join`:

```
df['Category1'] = [[y for y in x.split() if y in L] for x in df['Mention']]
df['Category2'] = ['/'.join(y for y in x.split() if y in L) for x in df['Mention']]
print (df)
                                        Mention          Category1  \
0  camera in sentences and display in sentences  [camera, display]   
1                     camera in sentences price    [camera, price]   

        Category2  
0  camera/display  
1    camera/price
```

Comment: the result gives me 'camera/display/camera' is the Mention is 'camera in sentences, and display or camera in sentences.' Do you know how to solve this? I only want one camera in result

Comment: @Aimee - add here `apply(set)` like `df['Category'] = df['Mention'].str.findall(pat).apply(set).str.join('/')`

Comment: And for another soklution use `df['Category1'] = [list(set([y for y in x.split() if y in L])) for x in df['Mention']]` or `df['Category2'] = ['/'.join(set(y for y in x.split() if y in L)) for x in df['Mention']]`

Answer (score 1):

```
some_words = ['camera','display','price','memory']
def check_it(sentences, words):
   find_words = []
   for word in words:
      if word in sentences:
         find_words.append(word)
   return find_words
t = check_it('display has camera and price is', some_words)
print t
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check the words in each sentence?

```
wordsList = ['camera','display','price','memory'(will have 200+ words in the list)]

def check_it(sentence, wordsList):
    wordString = ''
    flag = False
    counter = 0
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word in wordsList:
            if counter != 0:
                wordString = wordString + '/' + word
            else:
                wordString = word
            flag = True
            counter += 1
    if flag:
        return wordString
    elif not flag:
        return 'Others'
```

Comment: result will only return 'other', does not return the words in the list

Comment: I just edited it. I added sentence.split() because before it was checking each character rather than each word.